# Auto generate Swagger documentation for APIs written in vanilla Python

Tags: python, swagger

I am writing APIs in vanilla Python and further it would be deployed on AWS lambda. I want to auto generate swagger documentation for those API. I have worked with frameworks like Django Rest-framework and FastAPI and auto generating documentation for the API written in these Framework requires to install a PIP package and the swagger UI documentation is all ready with almost no efforts.

I wonder how those packages may have been written to make this happen. Is there way or a package which would help me do the same with my APIs?

Comment: How do you plan deploy these APIs? If you are using API gateway you can download the swagger files after you published a stage.

Comment: Ohh yes I just tried it after your comment. It does generate swagger YMAL which could be exported but how can I make it read the required query parameters, payload and response's status code and JSON?

Comment: we had the same issue and wrote a lambda function that called the API gateway export function (as propsed by @TobiasBruckert) to expose the open api specification _after_ deployment. however this stripped all model information/did not include model information that we had configured during deployment. we ended up generating the open api spec as part of the the deployment process and uploaded it to S3 where API gateway can expose it via standard S3 connectivity. We also used the generated spec as deployment descriptor for the GW (injected it into the SAM template)...it's not nice, but works...

Comment: @mrxra you should have a look into this approach.  https://github.com/sylwit/aws-serverless-swagger-ui.css works very well for me if you use version 3 and AWS extensions during the export I have all the model details as well.

Comment: @TobiasBruckert for me the exported YAML does not provide the sufficient information. Are there any python libraries I can use to customise the auto generated YAML?

Comment: Sorry haven't used it yet but  that could work https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation